# Debugging where rendered JS output is going

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails 3 application using unobtrusive Javascript on a link_to, to create a small window requiring user input. Here's the original button (for when a Client adds a Cat):

```
<%= link_to "New Cat", new_client_cat_path(@client), :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
```

In app/controllers/cats_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @cat = @client.cats.build
  @submit_label = "Create"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { }
  end
end
```

In app/views/cats/new.js.erb:

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@cat) %> .details').html('<%= escape_javascript render("new") %>');
```

In app/views/cats/_new.html.erb:

```
<h2>New Cat</h2>
<%= form_for [@client, @cat] do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<%= f.submit @submit_label, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", @client, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
```

My problem is that I don't see the rendered "new" window. The log file shows that these pages got rendered:

```
Rendered cats/_new.html.erb (3.8ms)
Rendered cats/new.js.erb (5.4ms)
```

How can I tell where the output is getting rendered to, so that I can figure out why I don't see it in the same window where the user clicked the "New Cat" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning render("new").  Instead you probably want to render a partial.  So extract the actual form definition from your new view,  and put them in a partial '_new.html.erb'

so your new.html.erb would contain

```
<%= render :partial=>'new' %>
```

and your new.js.erb:

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@cat) %> .details').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial=>"new") %>');
```

I'm still not sure this completely solves what you are trying to do,  but It should get you going in the right direction.  For example,  what element are you putting the returned HTML into?  It would have to be an element surrounded by an existing form_for.   You could do this maybe:

```
<%= form_tag  '/thing/create',  :html=>{:style=>'display:none'} do %>
  <div id='newform'>
    <%= render(:partial=>'new') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then:

```
$('#newform').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial=>"new") %>');
$('#newform').show;
```

Just be aware this approach PRECLUDES using this:

```
<%= form_for @resource  do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :foo %>
<% end %>
```

You can't ship the enclosing f block to to the controller and have the controller action try and process this in the partial:

```
<%= f.text_field :foo %>
```

So you have to resort to:

```
<%= form_tag .... do %>
  <%= render_partial=>'new' %>
<% end %>
```

and in _new.html.erb

```
<%= text_field_tag , 'thing[foo]', @thing.foo %>
```

When the controller,  in response to the AJAX request, sends back HTML, it's directed to the browser in general,  contained WITHIN the HTML are instructions on what element on the broswer page get's affected.

For example  you could do this:

```
render :js=>"$('#foobar').html('<h1>TITLE</h1><p>foobar</p>')";
```

or this:

```
render :js=>"$('#barfoo').html('<h1>TITLE</h1><p>barfoo</p>')";
```

each one will affect different elements on your page.

Comment: Thanks, @RadBrad. The original question was that I have a link_to which is now AJAX - so it doesn't refresh the entire screen. I wanted the user to be able to click on the link, and set up a little dialog box in a corner of the screen (a sidebar).

Comment: Yea,  that's kind of the recipe I presented.  You're link has remote=>true,  so you're sending an AJAX request to the controller,  it's returning javascript,  which completes your hidden form and then unhides it.

Comment: Right, but somehow, I don't properly understand how to figure out where the HTML is going. Earlier today, someone suggested I use the remote=> true for the link_to, so that I would not lose the user's main Client screen, while I pop up the window to get the user's input. I am trying right now to prepare a little sample app to show it. Do you have an email address I could send a pointer to? I am very grateful for your help on this.

Comment: Your approach is good - and now it works if I open it in a different tab. What I don't understand yet is how to deal with the HTML that comes back - how to put it on the original screen where the user clicked the button.

Comment: I am an "old programmer" too :)

Comment: Thanks! You have a very interesting statement in your answer- "it would have to be an element surrounded by an existing form_for." Why does it have to be surrounded by a form_for? And on your edit, could you show me one where you take the output of the "newform" and put it into "#foobar"? (In other words, I am not sure I see yet how to tie the pieces together.) Thanks again for all this help, @RadBrad.

Comment: Yes, it works without that, @RadBrad. I still have things to learn about all of this, but thanks so much for working with me on this.

Comment: If you're still around, @RadBrad, I just posted a question "How to fix broken JQueryUI Datepicker". I'm trying to figure out why a Datepicker in the rendered HTML is not getting hooked in to the Javascript definition. Thanks.